# Feature not found when predicting?

Tags: r, survival

Why does the following code produce an error?

The error is still present even if I remove the `CO-APPLICANT` feature.

I'm using the `censored` package in R

```
remotes::install_github("tidymodels/censored")
library(censored)

cph_fit <- 
  proportional_hazards() %>%
  fit(Surv(DURATION, DEFAULT) ~ . , data = train)

applicant <- data.frame(
  PURPOSE = "Radio/Tv",
  SEX= "Male_single",
  RESIDENCE = "Own_res",
  PROPERTY = "Real_Estate",
  CHK_ACCT = "<0",
  
  HISTORY = "2",
  AMOUNT = 3200,
  SAV_ACCT = "1",
  EMPLOYMENT = "1Yr<=...<4Yr",
  INSTALL_RATE = 2,
  
  `CO-APPLICANT` = "Yes",
  GUARANTOR = "No",
  
  PRESENT_RESIDENT = "2Yr<...<=3Yr",
  AGE = 35,
  OTHER_INSTALL = "No",
  NUM_CREDITS = 2, 
  JOB = "SkilledEmployee/Official",
  NUM_DEPENDENTS = 2,
  TELEPHONE = "Yes",
  FOREIGN = "No"
)

predict(cph_fit, applicant, type = "survival", time = 1:30)
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'CO-APPLICANT' not found

Comment: 1) This looks like a programming question, not a statistics question. So it should be asked on Stack Overflow instead. 2) I can't get your code to run because the `train` data isn't included. 3) R really does not like hyphens or spaces in names. I suggest either: renaming to `COAPPLICANT`, asking on SO with a complete reprex, or editing this question to highlight what the statistical issue is.